I keep getting 'Something went wrong' using Twitter OAuth 2.0 in NestJS
So first, This is my Twitter Developer User authentication settings:

I am trying to use the Twitter passport OAuth2 package provided by @superfaceai in my NestJS backend, I don't mind to change the package as long as it works;
This is my Twitter Strategy that I use in my authentication module:
@Injectable()
export class XTwitterStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'twitter') {
  constructor() {
    console.log(process.env.X_CLIENT_ID);
    console.log(process.env.X_CLIENT_SECRET);
    console.log(encodeURIComponent(process.env.X_CALLBACK_URL));
    super({
      clientID: process.env.X_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.X_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: encodeURIComponent(process.env.X_CALLBACK_URL),
      clientType: 'confidential',
    });
  }

  async validate(
    _accessToken: string,
    _refreshToken: string,
    profile: any,
    done: any,
  ): Promise<void> {
    const { emails, displayName, photos } = profile;

    console.log(profile);

    const user: OAuthUser = {
      provider: 'xtwitter',
      email: emails[0].value,
      name: displayName,
      avatar: photos[0].value,
    };

    done(null, user);
  }
}

This is my .env:
X_CLIENT_ID=...
X_CLIENT_SECRET=...
X_CALLBACK_URL=http://127.0.0.1:3000/auth/twitter/callback

And this is my authentication controller:
  @Public()
  @Get('twitter')
  @UseGuards(XTwitterOAuthGuard)
  public async twitterAuth(): Promise<void> {}

  @Public()
  @Get('twitter/callback')
  @UseGuards(XTwitterOAuthGuard)
  public async twitterAuthCallback(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Res() res: Response,
  ): Promise<void> {
        // the register/login handling goes here, i removed the function code to make things shorter, it doesn't get here anyways.
  }
}

I also added the express-session middleware to my main file:
  app.use(
    session({
      secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
    }),
  );

Everything looks good to me, so I am not sure where things go wrong, they don't show any relevant error messages/codes, all I get is the 'Something went wrong' screen;

I would appreciate if anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong here, I did the Google OAuth in the same way and it worked perfectly. Thank you in advance !
